# Trouble understanding the logic of a simple recursion (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, function, recursion, return

1) I think I understand this first one as I notice the recursion goes in order from n to n-1 and exits the current level it's in until it reaches the base of 0 and exists. I included some puts statements puts to map and follow the recursion.

```
def array_push(answer, n)                              #1. array push (RECURSIVE)
  puts "B n: #{n} inception map"; return answer if n <= 0;
  puts ". n: #{n} inception map"; answer << n; 
  puts "A n: #{n} inception map"; return array_push(answer, n-1)
end
puts array_push([], 4)
```

2) However when it goes in the opposite direction, this is where I'm lost... I'm confused as to why the function doesn't return false at the instant it hits "return false if n <= 0" statement. According to my understanding, my "B" and "." puts statements gets evaluated first and my "A" puts statement gets evaluated after the "return false statement".

```
def reverse_push(answer, n)                          #2. reverse push (RECURSIVE)
  puts "B n: #{n} inception map"; return false if n <= 0 ## <== right here ##
  puts ". n: #{n} inception map"; reverse_push(answer, n-1)
  p answer
  puts "A n: #{n} inception map"; return answer << n
end
puts reverse_push([], 4)
```

Comment: It looks like the first one returns [4,3,2,1] and the second one side-effects the passed array, adding 1,2,3,4 to it and returns false.  Is that not what happens?  The reversal happens because the second function changes the array on it's way _out_ of the recursion.

Comment: thanks for the reply. What I find weird is the false statement doesn't appear on my console. I can take out the false and just leave it as return if n <= 0 and the whole function seemingly still works the same way.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense.  I predicted just how you did, but that's mistaken.  Will explain in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing makes sense.  Think of the call stack:

```
caller -> r([],4) -> r([],3) -> r([],2) -> r([],1) -> r([],0)
caller -> r([],4) -> r([],3) -> r([],2) -> r([],1) <- false
caller -> r([],4) -> r([],3) -> r([],2) <- [1]
caller -> r([],4) -> r([],3) <- [1,2]
caller -> r([],4) <- [1,2,3]
caller <- [1,2,3,4]
```

False is returned at the end of the trip up the stack.  The returns from that second function on the way back down the stack return an array.

Comment: ah this is helpful. the diagram makes sense.

Comment: glad it helped.  if you think it's correct, feel free to mark it correct using the checkmark under the votes indicator.